# Ubuntu 13.04 battery indicator problems

Tags: battery

I installed ubuntu 13.04 with no problems but in the last 2 days the power indicator is screwing up. it says charging when i pull the cord out and when i put it in sometimes it says no charging. Sometimes it charges and sometimes it doesnt. just today my laptop died wile plugged in. with low screen brightness and no programs open and almost nothing running in the backround. please help

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem today and was able to fix it by removing the hdd from the system and then putting it back in.... (i tried about 20 different things) but it worked and my battery is now happy and healthy charging away again

Comment: are there any other solutions? have this on a laptop with a non-removable HDD....

Answer (score -1):

you could try deleting or overwriting your battery stats, normally you can do this by putting your computer on the lowest power settings and litting it tottally die.

then put it back on normal power, and charge it to 100% with the laptop on (i reccomend an hour longer than after it says 100%) and then let it discharge again

note there is no garuntee on this and i suggest trying other answers first as this takes ages and sometimes (more than most in my experience) does not work haha