# Ubuntu 13.04 Battery Indicator Issue

Tags: indicator, power-management, battery

I have an HP pavilion g6 laptop with Ubuntu 13.04 installed. Recently I installed jupitor for ubuntu 13.04 and uninstalled in due to some issues. I don't know whether it is the reason but now my battery indicator in ubuntu has gone crazy. When I plugged my laptop in, it indicates that the battery is low with red battery icon. When I unplugged, it shows battery is charging. I previously looked at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/295081/ubuntu-13-04-battery-indicator-problems) question but no answer found for my case. Can anybody give me a solution.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open terminal and put this command

```
sudo aptitude reinstall gnome-power-manager
```

it's may help you to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

I don't know this is a solution or not but try this,

Setting --> Power -->

Show battery status --> change it to When battery is charging/in use[image]

Comment: Please do not post duplicate answers on different questions. It just creates more work for the moderators. If the questions are so similar that the same answer works on each, then the later of the two is likely a duplicate and should be flagged as such.